# Can a Simperium bucket have multiple callbacks of the same type

Tags: callback, simperium

I'm using Simperium (JS, on the client), and I have a situation where I need to register multiple `ready` handlers: one that marks the container I'm storing the data in as finished loading (so I can display it to the user), and another that checks if the currently active route matches one of the objects we just loaded, and re-runs the route handler if that is the case.

The thing is, using bucket.on(signal, handler) seems to overwrite the first applied handler with the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a single handler is supported at the moment. We'd welcome any feedback on this though.

Comment: I _think_ it makes sense to be able to have multiple handlers on an event. My use case may be narrow though. Basically, I have a library that turns a bucket into a KnockoutJS observableArray, and part of that uses `ready` to set an internal flag. But it is useful for the end-client level code to be able to set a `ready` handler too. I do have a workaround. I'll write it up in some detail soon.

Comment: Ok please let us know if you write it up. What you're trying to do makes sense, it shouldn't be a big impact to add this to the library, we'll make that change.